# Bittorrent- embedded tracker issue HTTP error 401

Tags: http, bittorrent

I've created my own private torrent file, and I'm testing it on another PC with it's own completely separate internet connection, but it gets stuck on status 'connecting to peers' and nothing downloads.

Here's what I did in creating my private torrent file,

1. Enabled 'bt.enable_tracker' and reset BitTorrent.
2. Check port and checked that it's open.
3. Created new torrent and inserted the following trackers,

http://External-IP:Port-Number/announce

http://localhost:Port-Number/announce

(of course replacing 'External-IP' and 'Port-Number' with my own).

4. Ticked 'Start seeding' and created torrent file.
5. Torrent file is now present on host PC.
6. Opened torrent file on second PC, but this is where it gets stuck on status 'connecting to peers'. For http://External-IP:Port-Number/announce - the status is HTTP Error 401. For http://localhost:Port-Number/announce, the status is invalid info hash and/or peer id. Where should i get the username and password from for the embedded bittorrent tracker?

I've also tried connecting via a third PC on the same LAN, but it gets stuck with the same status.

All other torrents, public and private site trackers download and seed just fine.

Any ideas where I am going wrong please?

Thank you

Comment: what ports have you forwarded? note that unless you have a rather sophisticated gateway router, it probably doesn't support Hair-pin NAT, which is required for hosts inside the LAN to send traffic to the public IP and and have it be handled by port forwarding rules, so that may explain the issue with the LAN hosts.

Comment: @FrankThomas i have forwarded the port as per the "port used for incoming connections" given in the bittorrent application.